# Require a node_module from within a subfolder

Tags: node.js, node-modules

So I have some node.js files

```
/folder/app.js
/folder/node_modules/moduleIwanttoload
/folder/subfolder/file.js
```

how do I require `moduleIwanttoload` from file.js?

Comment: It should be simply require 'moduleIwantoload'.

Comment: Oops yup that worked the npm readme just had the wrong name, I think...

Answer (score 8):

you can use subfolder files like this into app.js

```
var file = require('./subfolder/file.js');
```

and in the folder of node-modules you can just use it like

```
var moduleIwanttoload = require("moduleIwanttoload");
```

Answer (score 2):

If the module you want to load is a dependency contained in "node_modules" you can simply use

```
require("moduleIwanttoload")
```

Node JS will trace the directory tree down to the first folder in which it finds a "node_modules" directory and looks for the given dependency in it.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to access (import ) a module in app folder from a sub folder( i.e. current folder is a sub folder in the app folder) you can use ../ to access them e.g.  access common.js in app folder from appfolder/sub2/test2.js as ../../common.js

`const common= require("../../common.js");`